# Number of solutions to a linear equation over a finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

In "general" an underdetermined system has infinitely many solutions, whereas an overdetermined system has no solution and if the system has the same number of equations and unknowns then it has a unique solution.

Does this apply also over finite fields? More precisely, consider the finite field $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for a prime $p$. And consider the following system with one linear equation and two unknowns:
$$a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 = z \mod{p},$$
where $a_1, a_2$ are the coefficients, and $x_1, x_2$ are the unknowns.

How many solutions does it have? When does it have a unique solution?
(I'm especially interested in equations where one of the coefficients is 1, i.e., either $a_1 = 1$ or $a_2 = 1$)

Comment: Not every system with the same number of equations and unknowns has a unique solution

Comment: @BenGrossmann When is that true though?

Comment: Such a system of equations (one with the same number of equations and unknowns) has a unique solution iff its matrix of coefficients is invertible, which holds iff the matrix has non-zero determinant

Comment: Surely any book on linear algebra deals with Gauss Elimination/RREF ?

Comment: @BenGrossmann That isn't quite right: there can be more equations than variables so we can't speak of "invertible" or of determinant. Something like full rank and not inconsistent?

Comment: @ancientmathematician I meant to refer specifically to the case where the number of equations and variables is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a_1 = 1$, then this equation can be rewritten as
$$
x_1 = z - a_2 x_2.
$$
Thus, the equation has one solution for each possible value of $x_2$, which is to say that it has $p$ solutions. A similar approach can be applied as long as one of the coefficients is non-zero. The solution cannot be unique.

Comment: Would it be unique if I had two equations like $x_1 + a_2 x_2 = z$ and $a_1 x_1 + x_2 = y$?

Comment: Only if $a_1a_2 \neq 1$

Comment: You mean both $a_1 \neq 1$ and $a_2 \neq 1$ and not the product $a_1 \cdot a_2 \neq 1$, right?

Comment: @pandora No, I do mean the product $a_1\cdot a_2$.

Answer (score 1):

You start from a wrong result... "if the system has the same number of equations and unknowns then is has a unique solution". Think of
$$
\begin{cases}
x +y& = 1\\
x +y& = 2
\end{cases}
$$